# Adding array of objects to object

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am trying to return some data as JSON.

I have an array of values:

```
[
  { FieldValue: '102969', count: 1 },
  { FieldValue: 'DBFL', count: 26 },
  { FieldValue: 'Daniel', count: 1 },
  { FieldValue: 'KNI', count: 9 },
  { FieldValue: 'ON', count: 895 },
  { FieldValue: 'Ole', count: 4 },
  { FieldValue: 'TNJ', count: 133 }
]
```

That I am trying to add to an object, in order to get an object with a fieldname, and a values array

```
const objectToReturn = {
      FieldName: row.FieldName,
      FieldValues: []
    };
objectToReturn.FieldValues.push(values);

returnArr.push(objectToReturn);
console.log(returnArr);
```

This gives

```
[
  { FieldName: 'Customer ID', FieldValues: [ [Array] ] },
  { FieldName: 'Order No', FieldValues: [ [Array] ] },
  { FieldName: 'Technician ID', FieldValues: [ [Array] ] }
]
```

I've tried using JSON.stringify(values) in stead, giving me this return

```
{
    FieldName: 'Technician ID',
    FieldValues: [
      '[{"FieldValue":"102969","count":1},{"FieldValue":"DBFL","count":26},{"FieldValue":"Daniel","count":1},{"FieldValue":"KNI","count":9},{"FieldValue":"ON","count":895},{"FieldValue":"Ole","count":4},{"FieldValue":"TNJ","count":133}]'
    ]
  }
```

Comment: have you tried this instead, `objectToReturn = {
      FieldName: row.FieldName,
      FieldValues: [...values]
    };`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to write something like this,

```
const objectToReturn = {
      FieldName: row.FieldName,
      FieldValues: [...values]
    };
objectToReturn.FieldValues.push(values);

returnArr.push(objectToReturn);
console.log(returnArr);
```

I don't agree with other answers as they will have the object reference problem, I assume you need to have a copy of values array not the array itself

Comment: Thank you Deepak, the objectToReturn.FieldValues.push(values); is obsolete now, but the spread operator worked

Answer (score 1):

you can use spread operator

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax#description

for example:

```
FieldValues: [...values]
```

or

```
objectToReturn.FieldValues.push(...[values]);
```

Comment: Thank you Kavin, I'll read up on the spread operator - this worked wonders :)

Answer (score 0):

Hi you can try to do this :

```
objectToReturn.FieldValues = values
```

but you need to declare your object as a variable